# Implementing Binary tree in java

Tags: data-structures

I am new to datastructure.I am trying to implement Binary tree using Linked List.

I need a few clarifications in implementing it.

i)For inserting a new value in tree,Whether we should backtracking and Tree traversal in implementing it.

ii)Please suggest me cases for Searching and Deleting a value also.

iii)Please suggest me the correct material for implementing all type of Trees.

Comment: This is more a google question than a SO question ..

Comment: @sinclair i couldn't get the proper guidelines from google,thats why i posted in SO

Comment: A LinkedList for a Tree doesn't make much sense because a Node has multiple children in a tree while a LinkedList only has one forward "link"

Comment: @cricket_007 then can you suggest me which is the best way to implement binary tree or all types of trees?

Comment: "Best" is relative. I prefer a recursive approach, and here is a Google result for "implement binary tree in java" http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/binary-search-tree-complete-implementation/

Comment: As far as "all-types" ... n-ary trees are simple because you just keep a list of all the children references. AVL, Red-Black, or splay trees can't be implemented as simply

Comment: @cricket_007 Even while using recursive approach ,we need to either use array or linked list ? or there any other ways without using those techniques ?

Comment: You could use [an array for a heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation), but I recommend making your own `Node` class that holds the references to it's children. For example, `class Node { int value; Node left; Node right; }`

Comment: @cricket_007  i was using this "class Node { int value; Node left; Node right; }" only  and its similar to linked list rite ?.I am new,so can you suggest me ?

Comment: Similar, but a Linked-List node doesn't have the `left` field

Comment: @cricket_007 tanx man ,you made my day

Answer (score 1):

your Linked List should show something like this: `a->b->c->d->e->f-> ...`
where your tree will look like the picture at the end.
where a is the root with left child b and right child c. b has left child d and right child e and c has only a left child f.

i) you can put the new value at the end of the Linked List. No need to travel the Tree

ii) I'm assuming your Tree will not be a sorted binary tree. So for searching for a value k, you need to go through the whole Linked List. this will take O(n) as your time.

For deleting a variable, you can delete the node in Linked List and everything will be shifted. so for instance in the picture above if you delete d, you can see the result in the picture where f will be replacing d.

iii) Could you specify what do you mean by all types of Tree?

Hope this helps.

[Deleting a node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beubI.png)

Comment: your suggestion regarding binary tree through linked list is good,in binary tree here there is no need to know about the left or right child  .But i wanted a standard procedure for all type of trees ,it may be binary search tree,n-ary tree etc.For Ex:Lets consider a binary search tree where inserting nodes will be different one considering left node and right node.Please can u suggest me how to do handle it. i.e I need the Connection traversal between the parent and child

Comment: If the right and left child is different, then in your linked list, the nth nodes right child would be the (2n)th node and its left child would be the (2n+1)th node. so you can find every nodes children. this is for the binary tree. You can expand the same thing to a n-ary tree. for example, if it is a 5-tree , nth node's children would be: 5n-3 , 5n-2, 5n-1, 5n and 5n+1